# Proper way to replicate fixed pipe behaviour in GLSL v 1.3 and above?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm getting frustrated with the lack of clarity in the documentation about GLSL and what is allowed, deprecated and recommended in the different versions.

I have a bunch of fragment shaders that I'm writing in GLSL version 1.3. They work, but there is one mysterious bug which I suspect may appear because I'm not specifying any vertex shader, instead relying on the deprecated `gl_TexCoord[i]` variable to get texture data. In any event, I do wish to do things the standard and recommended way.

So what I'm asking is this: What is the proper, minimal example of a vertex shader which does nothing other than replicate the fixed pipe functionality in regards to vertex positioning and texture coordinate interpolation in GLSL 1.3, and how do I read the texture coordinate in my fragment shader?

My attempt right now looks like this:

```
// Vertex shader
#version 130
  out vec2 texCoord;

  void main()
  {
    gl_Position = vec4(gl_Vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    texCoord = 0.5 * gl_Position.xy + vec2(0.5, 0.5);
  }

//Fragment shader
#version 130
  in vec2 texCoord;
  uniform sampler2D tex;
  out vec4 outColor;

  void main() {
    outColor = texture2D(tex, texCoord.xy);
  }
```

But this does not give the same result as simply omitting the vertex shader and replacing texCoord with `gl_TexCoord[0]` (in fact, I get no output data at all in my test). To top it off, my drivers are complaining that `gl_Vertex` is deprecated as well!

So please, could someone provide a standard-compliant, recommended example for how to simply do what the fixed pipe already does in GLSL >= 1.3? If the recommended way differs between versions above 1.3, I'd appreciate examples demonstrating that as well, if possible.

If it matters - and I hope it doesn't - my viewport is set up as follows (F#, but the code should be self-explanatory):

```
GL.Viewport(base.ClientRectangle.X, base.ClientRectangle.Y, base.ClientRectangle.Width, base.ClientRectangle.Height)
let ratio = (float base.ClientRectangle.Height) / (float base.ClientRectangle.Width)
GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection)
GL.Ortho(-0.5, 0.5, ratio/2.0, -ratio/2.0, -10., 10.)
GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So what I'm asking is this: What is the proper, minimal example of a vertex shader which does nothing other than replicate the fixed pipe functionality (...) ?

There is no static GLSL shader source that will replicate fixed function pipeline is a "one size, err, shader fits all" way. Many fixed function pipeline settings, like done with *glTexEnvi* translate into different shader code.

Your shader code makes no sense anyway. gl_Vertex transfers the vertex position (before transformation) and, unless you want to emulate texture coordinate generation, will not yield a texture coordinate.

---

#### EDIT due to comment:

Fully working, minimal GLSL example for OpenGL-2, uses GLFW for context and window creation, GLEW for extension loading.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>

static void pushModelview()
{
    GLenum prev_matrix_mode;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MATRIX_MODE, &prev_matrix_mode);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(prev_matrix_mode);
}

static void popModelview()
{
    GLenum prev_matrix_mode;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MATRIX_MODE, &prev_matrix_mode);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(prev_matrix_mode);
}

static const GLchar *vertex_shader_source =
"#version 120\n"
"void main()"
"{"
"   gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;"
"   gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;"
"   gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;"
"   gl_BackColor = gl_Color;"
"}\0";
GLuint shaderVertex = 0;

static const GLchar *fragment_shader_source = 
"#version 120\n"
"uniform sampler2D texCMYK;"
"uniform sampler2D texRGB;"
"void main()"
"{"
"   gl_FragColor = -texture2D(texCMYK, gl_TexCoord[0].st) + texture2D(texRGB, gl_TexCoord[0].st);"
"}\0";
GLuint shaderFragment = 0;

GLuint shaderProgram = 0;

#define TEX_CMYK_WIDTH 2
#define TEX_CMYK_HEIGHT 2
GLubyte textureDataCMYK[TEX_CMYK_WIDTH * TEX_CMYK_HEIGHT][3] = {
    {0x00, 0xff, 0xff}, {0xff, 0x00, 0xff},
    {0xff, 0xff, 0x00}, {0x00, 0x00, 0x00}
};
GLuint texCMYK = 0;

#define TEX_RGB_WIDTH 2
#define TEX_RGB_HEIGHT 2
GLubyte textureDataRGB[TEX_RGB_WIDTH * TEX_RGB_HEIGHT][3] = {
    {0x00, 0x00, 0xff}, {0xff, 0xff, 0xff},
    {0xff, 0x00, 0x00}, {0x00, 0xff, 0x00}
};
GLuint texRGB = 0;

GLfloat cube_vertices[][8] =  {
    /*  X     Y     Z   Nx   Ny   Nz    S    T */
    {-1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0}, // 0
    { 1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0}, // 1
    { 1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}, // 2
    {-1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0}, // 3

    { 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0},
    {-1.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0},
    { 1.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0},

    {-1.0, -1.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
    {-1.0,  1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0},
    {-1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
    
    { 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    { 1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
    { 1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0},
    { 1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
    
    { 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
    {-1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0},
    { 1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},

    {-1.0, 1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    { 1.0, 1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
    { 1.0, 1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0},
    {-1.0, 1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
};

static void draw_cube(void)
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 8, &cube_vertices[0][0]);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 8, &cube_vertices[0][3]);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 8, &cube_vertices[0][6]);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
}

static void bind_sampler_to_unit_with_texture(GLchar const * const sampler_name, GLuint texture_unit, GLuint texture)
{
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + texture_unit); 
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        GLuint loc_sampler = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, sampler_name);
        glUniform1i(loc_sampler, texture_unit);
}

static void display(double T)
{
    int window_width, window_height;

    glfwGetWindowSize(&window_width, &window_height);
    if( !window_width || !window_height )
        return;
    
    const float window_aspect = (float)window_width / (float)window_height;

    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);

    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.7, 1.0);
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-window_aspect, window_aspect, -1, 1, 1, 100);
    
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -5);

    pushModelview();
    glRotatef(T * 0.1 * 180, 0., 1., 0.);
    glRotatef(T * 0.1 *  60, 1., 0., 0.);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    bind_sampler_to_unit_with_texture("texCMYK", 0, texCMYK);
    bind_sampler_to_unit_with_texture("texRGB", 1, texRGB);

    draw_cube();
    popModelview();
    
    glfwSwapBuffers();
}

static int open_window(void)
{
#if 0
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);
#endif

    if( glfwOpenWindow(0, 0,     /* default size */
                       8,  8, 8, /* 8 bits per channel */
                       8, 24, 8, /* 8 alpha, 24 depth, 8 stencil */
                       GLFW_WINDOW) != GL_TRUE ) {
        fputs("Could not open window.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    if( glewInit() != GLEW_OK ) {
        fputs("Could not initialize extensions.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

static int check_extensions(void)
{
    if( !GLEW_ARB_vertex_shader ||
        !GLEW_ARB_fragment_shader ) {
        fputs("Required OpenGL functionality not supported by system.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

static int check_shader_compilation(GLuint shader)
{
    GLint n;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &n);
        if( n == GL_FALSE ) {
        GLchar *info_log;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &n);
        info_log = malloc(n);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, n, &n, info_log);
        fprintf(stderr, "Shader compilation failed: %*s\n", n, info_log);
        free(info_log);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

static int init_resources(void)
{
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);

    glGenTextures(1, &texCMYK);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texCMYK);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,  GL_RGB8, TEX_CMYK_WIDTH, TEX_CMYK_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureDataCMYK);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glGenTextures(1, &texRGB);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texRGB);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,  GL_RGB8, TEX_RGB_WIDTH, TEX_RGB_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureDataRGB);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    shaderVertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(shaderVertex, 1, (const GLchar**)&vertex_shader_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shaderVertex);
    if( !check_shader_compilation(shaderVertex) )
        return 0;

    shaderFragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(shaderFragment, 1, (const GLchar**)&fragment_shader_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shaderFragment);
    if( !check_shader_compilation(shaderFragment) )
        return 0;

    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, shaderVertex);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, shaderFragment);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    return 1;
}

static void main_loop(void)
{
    glfwSetTime(0);
    while( glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED) == GL_TRUE ) {
        display(glfwGetTime());
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if( glfwInit() != GL_TRUE ) {
        fputs("Could not initialize framework.\n", stderr);
        return -1;
    }

    if( !open_window() )
        return -1;

    if( !check_extensions() )
        return -1;

    if( !init_resources() )
        return -1;

    main_loop();
    
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not interested in things like glTexEnvi parameters. I am only interested in vertex and texture coordinates, so that I can use my fragment shader (excluded from the question for brevity) on textured primitives. Since my shader code is incorrect, would you be able to provide a functional example of how to do this?